# javafx - fx:controller in FXML

Tags: java, javafx, controller

I have the following code and I have a problem that if I don't have fx-controller in FXML file, it throws me a lot of errors on all on-action methods. i can run program without problems, but I'm afraid that if I compile the whole program on GIT, it won't work because of these errors.

Main

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

        launch(args);
    }
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {


        HlavniController c1 = new HlavniController();
        c1.showStage();
    }
}
```

Controller

```
    public HlavniController(){

        thisStage = new Stage();
        try{
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/hlavni.fxml"));
            loader.setController(this);
            thisStage.setScene(new Scene(loader.load()));
            thisStage.setTitle("Edu Organiser");
            thisStage.setResizable(false);


        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Errors onMouseClicked methods, which work, but throw errors, because dont have fx: controller in FXML.

```
<Label fx:id="label1" onMouseClicked="#clickLabel" prefHeight="20000.0" prefWidth="2000.0" text="" textAlignment="CENTER" />
<Label fx:id="label2" onMouseClicked="#clickLabel" prefHeight="20000.0" prefWidth="2000.0" text="" />
<Label fx:id="label3" onMouseClicked="#clickLabel" prefHeight="20000.0" prefWidth="2000.0" text="" />
<Label fx:id="label4" onMouseClicked="#clickLabel" prefHeight="20000.0" prefWidth="2000.0" text="" />
<Label fx:id="label5" onMouseClicked="#clickLabel" prefHeight="20000.0" prefWidth="2000.0" text="" />
<Label fx:id="label6" onMouseClicked="#clickLabel" prefHeight="20000.0" prefWidth="2000.0" text="" />
<Label fx:id="label7" onMouseClicked="#clickLabel" prefHeight="20000.0" prefWidth="2000.0" text="" />
```

Comment: [mcve] please .. (and no screenshots of text!)

Comment: please read the referenced help page and act accordingly ;) When using fxml, you have to provide application, controller, fxml and a complete stacktrace (if anything throws)

Answer (score 0):

You **may** define `onMouseClicked` even if you don't set `fx:controller` in FXML. So I'm guessing those are just warnings, that won't prevent the program from running.

However, from what you're showing your controller doesn't declare the method `clickLabel(MouseEvent)`. So You'd be better off completely removing those `onMouseClicked` from your FXML.